# Handlebars partial printing [Object object] when rendered

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to register a Handlebars partial so that it can be included in another view. I'm using Handlebars 2.0.0.

Here's the template:

```
{{> subNav}}

<h1>Issue name: {{ name }}</h1>
<h2>Issue id: {{ id }}</h2>

<section id="issue-sections">
  {{#each sections}}
    <li>
      {{> sectionsListItem}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</section>
```

Here is the partial:

```
<p>This is a sub navigation.</p>
```

I'm compiling all templates using the Handlebars precompiler like so:

```
handlebars views/partials/*.handlebars views/partials/**/*.handlebars -f .tmp/public/js/templates.js
```

In my application:

```
Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates;
```

When I run the following command in the console:

```
Handlebars.templates.issuesShow({'a':'b'});
```

This is the result:

```
"[object Object]<p>This is a sub navigation.</p>
<h1>Issue name: </h1>
<h2>Issue id: </h2>

<section id="issue-sections">

</section>"
```

I'm not sure why [Object object] is being printed out.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. I believe it was caused by a mismatch between the version of handlebars I had installed locally (handlebars 3.0) which I was using to precompile my templates and the version I installed via npm (handlebars 2.0) which I was using in the browser. I upgraded my project's handlebars npm package to 3.0 and everything is working swimmingly.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I found.  npm had updated handlebars to 0.10.2, which now used the handlebars 3.0.3 library to compile the templates; but my runtime library was still v2.  I updated the runtime library to 3.0.3 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. But, I believe the issue is that the templates are precompiled with the handlebars pre-compiler, and then again when they are assigned to Handlebars.partials.

There way be a more elegant solution for this, but I now have it working with the following commands that are run with grunt-exec.

`handlebars views/partials/**/*.handlebars > .tmp/public/js/templates.js`

This precompiles the templates, they will be available from `Handlebars.templates`

And then I also run.

`handlebars -p views/partials/**/*.handlebars >> .tmp/public/js/templates.js`.

This precompiles the same templates again, using the partials flag, and appends the output to the same templates file.

These are then available from `Handlebars.partials` and can also be used inside of other templates using the Handlebars include partial syntax : `{{> partialName }}`.

Comment: It's probably due to a version mismatch as noted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29639766/1170723.